# Why must I include a where clause column in group by if I am not returning that column as a result?, how can I aggregate duplicate results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that uses a column in the where clause but does not return that column:

```
SELECT 
    t1.upc, l1.description, l1.size, 
    l2.Name AS SectionName, l1.section, l3.Name, l1.department,
    (SELECT SUM(QuantitySold) 
     FROM ProductMovement  
     JOIN ProductsMaster ON ProductsMaster.upc = ProductMovement.upc 
     WHERE TimeID >= (SELECT TimeID 
                      FROM Time 
                      WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2016') 
       AND TimeID <= (SELECT TimeID 
                      FROM Time 
                      WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2017') 
       AND ProductsMaster.upc = l1.upc 
       AND (l1.department = 4 OR l1.department = 13) 
       AND (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)) AS Qty,
    (SELECT SUM(TotalSales) 
     FROM ProductMovement  
     JOIN ProductsMaster ON ProductsMaster.upc = ProductMovement.upc 
     WHERE TimeID >= (SELECT TimeID 
                      FROM Time 
                      WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2016') 
       AND TimeID <= (SELECT TimeID 
                      FROM Time 
                      WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2017') 
       AND ProductsMaster.upc = l1.upc 
       AND (l1.department = 4 OR l1.department = 13) 
       AND (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)) AS Sales
FROM 
    ProductMovement t1
JOIN 
    ProductsMaster l1 ON l1.upc = t1.upc
JOIN 
    EnterpriseSections l2 ON l2.SectionID = l1.section
JOIN 
    EnterpriseDepartments l3 ON l3.DepartmentID = l1.department
WHERE 
    (SELECT SUM(QuantitySold) 
     FROM ProductMovement  
     JOIN ProductsMaster ON ProductsMaster.upc = ProductMovement.upc 
     WHERE TimeID >= (SELECT TimeID 
                      FROM Time 
                      WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2016') 
       AND TimeID <= (SELECT TimeID 
                      FROM Time 
                      WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2017') 
       AND ProductsMaster.upc = l1.upc 
       AND (l1.department = 4 OR l1.department = 13) 
       AND (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
   l1.upc, t1.upc, l1.section, l2.Name, l1.description, l1.size, l1.department, l3.Name
```

When I run this without `t1.StoreID` in the `GROUP BY` clause I get the error:

> Column 'ProductMovement.StoreID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I add the column to group by I get duplicate results for every `t1.storeID` because I am aggregating all of my data anyway.

Why am I required to group by a column I am not returning and how can I aggregate these results?

Comment: It would be helpful to explain _what_ you are trying to achieve, preferably including an entity-relationship diagram describing the relationship between the many tables you have referenced.

Comment: Because technically you are not only using it in your query's WHERE clause, you are also using it in the WHERE clause of both of your *Column* sub-queries.  Column sub-queries have the same constraints as the columns themselves.  Try moving the `SUM(..)`s from inside the subqueries to surrond and contain the subqueries instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are "aggregating all of the data anyway", you may want to consider using two queries.

First query: Include all data for stores 3, 9, and 2 within your date range. And save this as a temp table.

Second query: Use your temp table as input.  But it's mostly the same query as you've written above, just without the checks for the stores.

Be sure to leave notes to people that the data is an aggregate of just those 3 stores.

Breaking it down into two steps will make it easier for future programmers finding this code to figure out what is happening.

Either that or...
you could try a `HAVING` clause instead of your ending `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT t1.upc, l1.description, l1.size, l2.Name AS SectionName, l1.section, l3.Name, l1.department,
    SUM(SELECT QuantitySold FROM ProductMovement  JOIN ProductsMaster ON 
        ProductsMaster.upc = ProductMovement.upc 
            WHERE TimeID >= (SELECT TimeID FROM Time WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2016') 
            AND TimeID <= (SELECT TimeID FROM Time WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2017') 
            AND ProductsMaster.upc = l1.upc 
            AND (l1.department = 4 OR l1.department = 13) 
            AND (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)) AS Qty,
    SUM(SELECT TotalSales FROM ProductMovement  JOIN ProductsMaster ON 
        ProductsMaster.upc = ProductMovement.upc 
        WHERE TimeID >= (SELECT TimeID FROM Time WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2016') 
            AND TimeID <= (SELECT TimeID FROM Time WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2017') 
            AND ProductsMaster.upc = l1.upc AND (l1.department = 4 OR l1.department = 13) 
            AND (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)) AS Sales
    FROM ProductMovement t1
    JOIN ProductsMaster l1 ON l1.upc = t1.upc
    JOIN EnterpriseSections l2 ON l2.SectionID = l1.section
    JOIN EnterpriseDepartments l3 ON l3.DepartmentID = l1.department
    GROUP BY l1.upc, t1.upc, l1.section, l2.Name, l1.description, l1.size, l1.department, l3.Name
    HAVING SUM(SELECT QuantitySold FROM ProductMovement  JOIN ProductsMaster ON 
            ProductsMaster.upc = ProductMovement.upc 
            WHERE TimeID >= (SELECT TimeID FROM Time WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2016') 
            AND TimeID <= (SELECT TimeID FROM Time WHERE FactDate = '1/14/2017') 
            AND ProductsMaster.upc = l1.upc 
            AND (l1.department = 4 OR l1.department = 13) 
            AND (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)) IS NOT NULL
```

This will check if your `Qty` aggregate is Not Null *after* the `GROUP BY` is completed. (Instead of before hand like the `WHERE` is doing.)
This is more busy code and a bit harder to follow.  If you have a small database, I'd recommend the two query solution.  If you have a huge database, the bigger query may be faster.

Best of luck :)

*EDIT*

Also pull your `SUM` functions outside the selects you have them in. Since you don't have a `GROUP BY` inside those selects, you are not aggregating them there. You are aggregating the outer select. I'll modify the code above to pull the `SUM` functions out to the main query.

Although, I'll reiterate... splitting your query in two (as described above) would solve the problem by removing StoreID's from the 2nd query.

Comment: Thanks, but this query is producing the same error: Column 'ProductMovement.StoreID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Ahhh yes... Quite possibly your `SUM` functions need to be outside the selects you have them in.  Since you don't have a `GROUP BY` inside those selects, you are not aggregating them there.  You are aggregating the outer select.  I'll modify the code above to pull the 'SUM' functions out to the main query.  (As a side note... splitting your query in two would solve the problem by removing StoreID's from the 2nd query.)

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I required to group by a column [ProductMovement.StoreID] I am not returning

You may not be returning the column but in order for sql server to process your query, it will still need to load it into memory because you have it in a sub-query in your select clause. Here is your query and I have omitted many parts for brevity:

```
SELECT 
    t1.upc, l1.description, l1.size, 
    l2.Name AS SectionName, l1.section, l3.Name, l1.department,
    (SELECT 
     WHERE 
       -- Here 
       (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)) AS Qty,
    (SELECT 
       -- Here 
       AND (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)) AS Sales
FROM 
    ProductMovement t1
JOIN 
    ProductsMaster l1 ON l1.upc = t1.upc
JOIN 
    EnterpriseSections l2 ON l2.SectionID = l1.section
JOIN 
    EnterpriseDepartments l3 ON l3.DepartmentID = l1.department
WHERE 
    (SELECT 
       -- Here 
       AND (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
   l1.upc, t1.upc, l1.section, l2.Name, l1.description, l1.size, l1.department, l3.Name
```

Look for `-- Here` in the above query to see where you are referencing `StoreID`. SQL Server will do the `Group by` and then the `Select` and since the select clause is referencing `StoreId`, SQL Server needs to keep the column around after the `Group by`. Since you have not used it in the `Group by` or in an aggregate function, it does not know how to deal with it: How can it possibly group by certain columns in the `Group by` clause if you are using a subquery in your `select` clause which is referencing a column that is not in the group by?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should only add columns that you are logically grouping to `GROUP BY`. I would suggest against using `GROUP BY` to reduce "accidental" duplicates in your result set caused by a `JOIN`. Grouping on large string values (which I imagine ProductsMaster.Description is) can degrade performance unnecessarily.

Here is one way I would recommend achieving what I **assume** you are trying to do (in a shorter way):

```
WITH Movement (
SELECT t1.upc,
       SUM(t1.QuantitySold) AS 'QuantitySold',
       SUM(t1.TotalSales) AS 'TotalSales'
FROM ProductMovement t1
WHERE t1.StoreID IN ( 2, 3, 9 )
  AND t1.TimeID >= (SELECT t.TimeID 
                    FROM [Time] t
                    WHERE t.FactDate = '1/14/2016') 
  AND t1.TimeID <= (SELECT t.TimeID 
                    FROM [Time] t
                    WHERE t.FactDate = '1/14/2017')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ProductsMaster l1
              WHERE l1.upc = t1.upc
                AND l1.department IN ( 4, 3 ))
GROUP BY t1.upc )

SELECT m.upc, l1.[description], l1.size,
       l2.[Name] AS 'SectionName', l1.section, l3.[Name], l1.department,
       m.QuantitySold,
       m.TotalSales
FROM Movement m
JOIN ProductsMaster l1 ON l1.upc = m.upc
JOIN EnterpriseSections l2 ON l2.SectionID = l1.section
JOIN EnterpriseDepartments l3 ON l3.DepartementID = l1.department;
```

Again, this is based on a lot of assumptions without knowing the entity relationships. However, it should give you the overall concept I am describing.

Answer (score 0):

to build on what codingyoshi said,
you're grouping the inner query aggregate by the outer query reference.

```
select *
from t1
inner join 
(select sum(value)
from ProductMovement
 where (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2))
```

your subquery has a reference to the outer column.  That is the same as using this:

```
select *
from t1
cross join 
(select sum(value), StoreID 
from ProductMovement group by StoreID) as sQuery
where (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)
```

More than likely you just need to change your where clause a bit
from this:

```
   AND ProductsMaster.upc = l1.upc 
   AND (l1.department = 4 OR l1.department = 13) 
   AND (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2)) IS NOT NULL
```

to this:

```
   AND ProductsMaster.upc = l1.upc )
   AND (l1.department = 4 OR l1.department = 13) 
   AND (t1.StoreID = 3 OR t1.StoreID = 9 OR t1.StoreID = 2) IS NOT NULL
```

though I wouldn't be surprised if you'll need to group by l1.upc for this reference:

```
   AND ProductsMaster.upc = l1.upc
```